# DynamoDB Composite key vs. Secondary Index

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm looking into DynamoDB and I think I understand the core concepts for composite keys (partition-key + sort-key) and secondary indexes.

Now, I'm curious about design best-practices for a rather simple case.

Let's say I have **50 million** books with a unique book-id and an author-id (plus additional fields):

```json
{
  "book_id": "ghjk-5678-kj78-98kl",
  "author_id": 1234567,
  "release_date": "1970-01-01",
  "genre": "Fiction"
}
```

I only *ever* have these two use-cases:

- Find book by `book_id` (20 million times **per day**)
- Find all books by `author_id` (once **per week**)

I *do not* want to find books by any other attribute.

What would be the "better" approach (and why)?

1. Use a composite key (`author_id` + `book_id`)
2. Use a single-attribute key (`book_id`) in combination with a secondary index on `author_id`
3. Stop overthinking it - that's premature optimization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use a composite key (`author_id` + `book_id`)

> This depends, id you know the `authorId` of the book when you find book by `bookId` then yes, that would make perfect sense.

- Use a single-attribute key (`book_id`) in combination with a secondary index on `author_id`

> If you don't know the `authorId` when you search a book, then this is a good option.

- Stop overthinking it - that's premature optimization

> This is a significant optimization, now is the time to decide.

| PK | SK | Data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Author1 | Book1 | Some info |
| Author1 | Book2 | Some info |
| Author1 | Book3 | Some info |
| Author4 | Book1 | Some info |
| Author2 | Book1 | Some info |
| Author2 | Book2 | Some info |

With this model not only can you get a book by `bookId` (as long as you know the `authorId`, you can also get all books related to an author.

You may not need an index in that case. But if you do not know the `authorId` for the most frequent request, your base table should be a `bookId` as PK, and your index will be like the above.

Comment: I _do_ know the author-id at _any_ time so your answer would suggest a composite-key rather than a secobdary index.

Comment: Of course, you save the cost of having an index as the table can now cater for all access patterns. It's a no-brainer.